# MySQL Workbench Import NULL from CSV

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I can't for the life of me make MySQL Workbench import NULL for blank cells in a CSV.

I've tried:

- blank
- NULL
- \N
- Each with and without ""

How the does one signify a cell is 'null' inside a CSV file I want to import into MySQL via Workbench?

Comment: Same problem... exported from another DB using Workbench and can't import nulls properly now, looks like developers forgot to test the import feature

Comment: I eventually gave up and did a command-line import `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` but it's tedious to list all the column headers...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since MySQL Workbench version 8.0.16 (released on 04/25/2019) there has been an additional option for uploading .csv file -- "null and NULL word as SQL keyword". When selecting this option as YES, the NULL expression without quotes in .csv file (,NULL, rather than ,"NULL",) will work for this purpose.

Comment: Nice find - I'll check this out when I have time.

Comment: Where is this option?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by updating your workbench to the newest.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you were trying to import a CSV into the model for creating insert scripts (where you won't get the same options described in the other answers), try the following:

```
\func NULL
```

You can also use this syntax to call functions like the following to insert the current date time when you forward engineer the model to the database:

```
\func CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest switching to Navicat for MySQL -- if only for the csv table import wizard. After repeated attempts to get the MySQLWorkbench Import Wizard to work for my CSV file, I gave up. I recalled using Navicat in an early project and it worked flawlessly. For this import, I was able to load my 15000+ row CSV with multiple null datetime values into my MySQL table without a problem.

Weird that MySQLWorkbench still hasn't solved this annoyance. But Navicat provides an easy alternative until they do.